# Why null return for PHP array?

Tags: php, json

So I've got a datafile that is to contain all of the "events" that is supposed to be in a JSON format as such:
`[{"id":"4f946d7a31b27", "title":"Floss the Otter", "start":1333252800, "end":1333339199}]`

Where more events would just be more JSON objects [{}, {}, ...]. I wrote a function to try and
get the datafile as an array of JSON objects to unshift a new event onto, and write it back out to the datafile, but I keep getting a null return, not the array.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $start = $_POST['start'];
  $end = $_POST['end'];
  $event = array(
                 'id' => md5($title),
                 'title' => $title,
                 'start' => $start,
                 'end' => $end
                 );
  $data = get_data();
  array_unshift($data, $event);

   if ($fp = fopen($data_file, "w")){
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($data));
    fclose($fp);
```

}

```
}

function get_data() {
  $str = "";
  if ($fp = fopen($data_file, "r")){
    while($line = fgets($fp)) {
      $str = $str . $line;
    }
    $data = json_decode($str, true);
    return $data == NULL ? array() : $data;
  }
}
```

If I write out the variable `$event` instead of the should be array `$data`, then the file contains a JSON object as it should, so I'm worried that my method to convert from file to array is incorrect. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is $data_file defined? Its not in your code, and doesnt appear to be defined in the get_data function either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<?php
    function get_data($data_file) {
      if (!file_exists($data_file)) {
        return array();
      }
      $str = trim(file_get_contents($data_file));
      return 0 < strlen($str) ? json_decode($str, true) : array();
    }

    if ($_POST) {
      $title = $_POST['title'];
      $start = $_POST['start'];
      $end   = $_POST['end'];
      $event = array(
        'id'    => md5($title),
        'title' => $title,
        'start' => $start,
        'end'   => $end
      );

      $data_file  = __DIR__ . '\file.ext'; // file that contains your json data
      $data_array = get_data($data_file);
      array_unshift($data_array, $event);

      file_put_contents($data_file, json_encode($data_array));
    }
```

Comment: Fixed typo (sizof -> sizeof)..

Comment: FYI, the `0 < sizeof($_POST)` part of `if ($_POST && 0 < sizeof($_POST))` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

`$data_file` is not defined in the `get_data` function, and so `fopen` will fail; the function does not `return` anything (and so is `NULL`).

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly the problem. I'm gonna give the answer to the other post because it was first and it solved it to, but thanks again!!